# Are const parameters identical to const reference parameters

Tags: c++, constants

I have a function

```
void h(A const a){...};
```

Is it possible that the behaviour will change if I make it:

```
void h(A const &a){..same body as above..};
```

You are free to define the type A as you wish.  Of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first overload, h cannot change 'a'. It is for all purposes const in the body of 'h'.
However, this involves a copy constructor to copy initialize 'a'.

Therefore, in the first case, it requires an accessible copy constructor in 'A'. By the same token, it  requires an accessible destructor in A.

In the second case, there is no copy initialization required, hence no accessible copy constructor/destructor of 'A's is required.

Also, in the first case 'a' will undergo 'slicing' if a derived object of 'A' is passed as argument. The second function will not have the 'slicing' issue as base class references can bind to derived objects. Hence, an accessible destructor is also not needed in this case.

In C++11, the first function would require 'A' to have an accessible 'copy' or 'move' constructor depending on how 'h' is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what happens in the copy constructor of your type `A`, yes you could get different behaviour.

As mentioned in the other answers, passing by value rather than by reference will cause the copy constructor of `A` to be executed, which is a separate path for the code to take.  If your class `A` handles some resource, then copying the class may end up passing in a different instance of that resource to the function.

Effectively it all depends on what class `A` actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: In your first example, a full copy of `a` is created on the stack. No matter what you call the function with, the copy constructor for A will be called, for the parameter you pass in. When the function exits, the destructor for `a` will be called. Depending on your implementation of `A` that can be very expensive.

Aditionally, the first function cannot be called for objects where the copy constructor is inaccessible, for abstract classes (if `A` is abstract), and if called with a class derived from `A`, the copy received within the function will be sliced.

The second function suffers from none of these limitations.

TL;DR: You should never use the first version (but your mileage may vary).

Comment: A good explanation of what happens, but the behaviour _could_ change depending on what happens in the copy constructor.

Comment: Well, if the class has mutable members, changing the prototype could well change the behaviour. A const method could still affect state outside the function if `a` is passed by const reference.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have written here about the cost of
copy-constructing `a` and potential slicing issues if this
gets passed some classed derived from `A` in the first case, these functions
have different signatures.

If `h` is a member function of some class and tries to overwrite a `virtual`
function `h` in a base class the two forms will be considered different
functions since their signatures differ. That means the first form cannot
overload the second.

If you then call `h` in the derived class via a pointer to the base class and
want `h` from the derived class to be called their signatures must be
identical. Otherwise the `h` from the base class will be called. This could
make an observable difference.